# SendKeys is not putting the value ToolsQA into the textfield

Tags: c#, selenium

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    IWebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();                                 
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form/");                 
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstname")).SendKeys("ToolsQA");
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys I'm a beginner to coding and StackOverflow, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Learning Selenium with C# to learn testing automation...

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? It doesn't open the URL? It types somwhere else? It crashes? Could be anything. Please be more specific

Comment: Hello @ThomasWeller I have updated my subject line - SendKeys is not putting the value ToolsQA into the textfield.

Comment: include the html markup of the form.

Comment: Form" href="http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/"><strong>Partial Link Test</strong></a></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="control-group"><a title="Automation Practice Table" href="http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-table/"><strong>Link Test</strong></a></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="control-group"><strong>First name:</strong> <input name="firstname" type="text"></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="control-group"><strong>Last name:</strong> <input id="lastname" type="text"></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I should use Name, instead of Id.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("firstname")).SendKeys("ToolsQA");
```